# Add empty row with index in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row

In all the examples and answers on here that I've seen, if there is the need to add an empty row ina Pandas dataframe, all use:

```
ignore_index=True
```

What should I do if i want to leave the current index, and append an empty row to the dataframe with a given index?

Comment: Use  `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df1.values, index, values=[" "] * len(df1.columns), axis=0),columns = df1.columns)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We using `reindex`

```
df.reindex(df.index.values.tolist()+['Yourindex'])
Out[1479]: 
             A    B
0          one   Aa
1          one   Bb
2          two   Cc
Yourindex  NaN  NaN
```

Data input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two'] ,
                   'B' : ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc'] })
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two'] ,
                   'B' : ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc'] })
new_df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(['New Index']))])
```